# Hint for solving $yy'' + y'^2 + 2a^2y^2 = 0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have p(y) = y' and p*dp/dy = y''. So the equation goes as:

$$ p\frac{dp}{dy} = - \frac{2a^2y^2 + p^2}{y}. $$

If proceed with this, I get the result:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \pm \sqrt{c/y^2 - a^2y^2} $$

And if I solve this with wolframalpha, I do not get the same result as it gives for the original equation - actually WA cannot even integrate it out normally, it becomes a long expression. Any tips?

EDIT: wolframa's solution: $y(x) = c_2*\sqrt{cos(ac_1+2ax)}$

Comment: You'd better add the Wlfram's answer too.

Comment: It would also be a good idea to give your solution that does not coincide with the one given by WolframAlpha.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
(y^2)'=2yy'\text{ and }(y^2)''=2(yy''+y'^2)
$$
which may serve to reduce your equation to
$$
(y^2)''+4a^2(y^2)=0
$$
As this is the equation for a harmonic oscillator you get
$$
y^2 = M\cdot\sin(2a(x+c)).
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$yy'' + y'^2 + 2a^2y^2 = 0\implies \frac{y''}{y} + \frac{y'^2}{y^2} + 2a^2 = 0$$

Now, if

$$q=\frac{y'}{y}\implies \frac{dq}{dx}=\frac{y''}{y}-\frac{(y')^2}{y^2}$$

thus

$$\frac{dq}{dx}+2q^2+2a^2=0\implies\frac{dq}{q^2+a^2}+2dx=0\implies\frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}\frac{q}{a}+2x=c_1$$

Some rearrangement leads to:

$$q=a\tan(a(c_1-2x))\implies\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2a\sin(a(c_1-2x))}{\cos(a(c_1-2x))}$$

$$\implies\frac{d}{dx}\log y = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}\log(\cos(a(c_1-2x)))\implies y=c_2\{\cos(a(c_1-2x))\}^{1/2}$$

where $c_1,c_2$ are arbitrary constants.